# how to write file in python-flask

Tags: python, flask

Is there any special instruction when I am writing a file in a flask environment? I first got "permission denied" error, and then I run the pycharm as administrator, and no error returned, but my file didn't get written(nothing happened!).

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    with open('test.txt', "wb") as test:
        test.write("I wrote in test!")
    return render_template('index.html')
```

I am doing a project that write a music midi file, store in the project directory, then play the midi on the webpage later to the user. But there seems no way that I can create a file in flask.

Comment: The file did get created, but in a directory you aren't expecting.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to write a text file not a binary file.

Try,

```
with open('test.txt', "w") as test:
        test.write("I wrote in test!")
```

Comment: There is no difference on Linux.

Comment: but, she did not mention linux